# Histogram statistical comparison reference recommendation

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I am currently wrestling with several pairs of discrete probability distribution histograms (n = 60,000,000+ for each) and are seeking to determine the significance of any and all dissimilarity between the histograms in each pair.

In my research meanderings, I have come across the [Bhattarcharyya distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance), which is nice and very straight forward to use - but, what is not clear to me is how to measure the statistical significance of the calculated distance.

**Is there a reference that explains the statistical significance of values determined when using the Bhattarcharyya distance?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found an answer regarding this. According to the conference paper [The Bhattacharyya Metric as an Absolute Similarity
Measure for Frequency Coded Data.](http://www.tina-vision.net/docs/memos/1997-001.pdf)
 (Thacker et al. 1997), the significance of the Bhattarcharyya distance:

> As the Bhattacharyya measure is equivalent to the Matusita measure we see that the Bhattacharyya metric is
>   a chi-squared type statistic in the sense of squared Euclidean distance, although unlike the chi-squared statistic,
>   the Bhattacharyya metric measures similarity in a domain where all errors are constant

and specifically, for histograms, the authors propose that the

> Bhattacharyya statistic $\sum_{i} \sqrt{R_i} \sqrt{S_i}$ as a measure of similarity between the
>   two histograms. For the case of two identical histograms we obtain $\sum_{i} \sqrt{R_i} = 1$ indicating a perfect match.

Where the probability distributions of each of the histograms are $R_i$ and $S_i$

and that

> Matusita and Bhattacharyya measures are themselves a form of test statistic but because of their construction
>   they require no systematic error correction.